# Typescript to return different interfaces based on argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to return different interfaces based on the argument passed to the method. This is what I have so far:

```
interface A {
    a: string;
}
interface B {
    b: string;
}
interface C {
    c: string;
}

export enum Type {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
  C = 'c',
}
interface Configs {
  a: A;
  b: B;
  c: C;
}

const get = <C extends Type>(name: C): Configs[C] => {
    if (name === Type.A) {
        return { a: 'true' } as A;
    }

    if (name === Type.B) {
        return { b: 'true' } as B;
    }

    if (name === Type.C) {
        return { c: 'true' } as C;
    }

    throw new Error('Unknown type')
}

// This works correctly
const b = get(Type.B);
```

The usage of the method works correctly; if I do `get(Type.B)` I do in fact get back the correct interface.

However, the method itself is giving me errors on the `return` statements, saying `property "x" is missing from A & B & C`. How can I write this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just use `Config[C]` as return type. We pass arguments, then generic function get type `C`, then get type for `Config[C]`.

However you have 3 return statement with difference type `A`、`B`、`C`，so compiler think return type of this function is `A & B & C`, then complain about `Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'A & B & C'` or something.

So you should just use `Config[C]` as return type, and compiler know what type it is.

```js
interface A {
    a: string;
}
interface B {
    b: string;
}
interface C {
    c: string;
}

export enum Type {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
  C = 'c',
}
interface Configs {
  a: A;
  b: B;
  c: C;
}

// use <C extends keyof Configs>(name: C) should be better
const get = <C extends Type>(name: C): Configs[C] => {
    if (name === Type.A) {
        return { a: 'true' } as Configs[C];
    }

    if (name === Type.B) {
        return { b: 'true' } as Configs[C];
    }

    if (name === Type.C) {
        return { c: 'true' } as Configs[C];
    }

    throw new Error('Unknown type')
}

// This works correctly
const b = get(Type.B);
```

You can see playground here: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=40&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20XALmQGcwpQBzAbiwF8tRJZEUAhTHPAIyNPJGp0G4aPCTIAwhzzIEvMpRr0sEAB4AHAPZQwyCCACuAW2QAVAJ7qU2XOgC8yAORxHAGk7sHjrm85SvCL70jKIskpogMMAUxNL4RKg0uDzIrEmyRBJKWFgIEaTIFBC6DgA8UmqQIAAmsRZWAHwAFCBwRhCZAJSZEVExANoSALrIdg1xuMAwyC1tKHYLZpYQAHSonRMyyFDFBlAgmPFOZAYQjsi0%20LESvdHEg0PpuMoyUzOt7aOL9ausGzZbXA7MB7A4YZApRwnM4XK7hSJ3B5PC45V7TWafBYOH4rCT-TiA4Ggw5yY5QU7nS5wa63AbDZEvPBgAAWUE0AHdkCAIJyAKJQNlQJqOACqIAA1iAOQcwMtHJ0hFgAPRKszM4CxdnacWxPICiAIMAAG3MuXyui4o0KxSaOL%20NCAA)